# How would I transfer data from node.js to a JavaScript client on another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js backend, I also have a website written in HTML, CSS & JS, but it runs on a different server than the Node.JS backend

I need to transfer data from the node.js to the website.

I cant upload my website to my node.js server because it wont be free anymore, I am doing this as a personal project so I would like it to stay free, the only way I found is to store the data in some kind of database and access it using the website, but cant find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Just expose your data using the Node.JS backend via an API. And make AJAX requests from the website to the backend.